# Adapting styles compare to the android sdk

Tags: android, styles

Basically, I created 2 values folders: values and values-v11.
I want that style to be applied to versions below 3.0:

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">

</style>
```

and that style to be applied above 3.0:

```
    <style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

  </style>
```

The problem is that eclipse marks the second style as an error.. why does it do that..and how can I fix it.

Here how the top of my manifest file looks like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DmitriMakovetskiy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="4.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the target sdk level to at least 11 in the manifest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Comment: it still shows me an error on this line:     <style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

Comment: @BlackFire27 - What's your project build target set to?